# How to disable ALT+TAB preview windows in Cinnamon?

Tags: 13.04, cinnamon

How do I disable ALT+TAB preview windows in Cinnamon?

See this the screenshot, to see what I mean.

[image: link]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1)** Right click in **cinnamon panel** > **settings** > **all settings**

[image]

[image]

**2)** In the settings settings window, click in **Switch to Advance Mode**.

[image]

**3)** Got to Preferences and click in **Windows**
[image]

**4)** Go to *"Alta-tab switcher style"* and Choose your favorite option: eg *(icon only, icon and window preview etc)*

[image]

**NOTE:** by default the option is in *"icons and thumbnails"*. So you can choose "icons only".

[image]